# Adding dependencies in Gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to move my Android project form IDEA to Android Studio with Gradle.
However, I am having difficulties with the dependencies. I removed my "lib" dir, so the jars would be retrieved from maven. But how do I correctly add them?

E.g. org.apache.commons.lang3

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.+'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:2.6.+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

This results in:

```
Failed to refresh Gradle project 'idoms-android'
         Could not find commons:commons-lang3:3.0.
```

It seems to be in the Maven Repository though.

Comment: I don't know if it has anything to do but your dependency says  `commons-lang3:2.6.+` and the error says `commons-lang3:3.0`, diferent versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing this at the top level (i.e., a peer of `android` and `dependencies`):

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

The `buildscript` block has `repositories` and `dependencies` for the *build process*. You also need `repositories` and `dependencies` at the top level for the dependencies for your project itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
}
```

Add above line in your build.gradle file, this is the latest version.

Also you can check it from here:

[mvnrepository, Apache Commons Lang » 3.4](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4)